# Как открыть сайт flask (python) в открытый доступ

Tags: flask, хостинг, python-3.5

Допустим есть небольшая страница на flask:

```
from flask import Flask
server = Flask(__name__)
@server.route('/')
def index():
    return 'It\'s works!'
server.run()
```

Есть личным домен (к примеру simple.com).

Как открыть эту страницу в открытый доступ с этим доменом, чтобы к примеру я мог с телефона с другого конца города зайти по адресу simple.com и я увидел надпись 'its works!' ?

Но прошу заметить, что я хочу, чтобы мог зайти не только я, а абсолютно любой человек (или бот :) ).

Очень хороший вариант - ngrok, но он даётся на время и + нельзя поставить свой домен.

P.S. Короче говоря, как сделать хостинг из своего личного ПК?

Comment: И ещё, если посоветуете технологию наподобие nginx, то расскажите поподробней, как открыть доступ к странице для всех, а не только localhost

Comment: Почему наподобие, чем сам nginx не угодил?

Comment: А по теме вопроса фласк здесь ни при чём, вам нужно получить у провайдера внешний статический IP-адрес и настроить роутер, фаервол и NAT (при их наличии) на использование какого-то TCP-порта, на котором будет работать flask или nginx (для http обычно порт 80)

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/

Comment: 1. Статический ip есть.
2. Роутер настроен (открыты порты 80 и 443)
В итоге не услышал того, как прикрутить домен.
Кстати только что попробовал wampserver, смог зайти с телефона, но там трудности с flask. + опять же, как настроить DNS, чтобы по домену simple.com (к примеру), вылетал результат в виде html странички (которая генерируется flask'ом)

Comment: @user299380 зайти в панель управления доменами на сайте того регистратора, у которого приобретали домен, прописать там NS-записи DNS-хостера. Потом зайти в панель управления доменами DNS-хостера и прописать там A-запись, указывающую на ваш IP-адрес. Иногда регистратор сам предоставляет услугу DNS-хостинга.

Comment: @user299380 ну или можно поднять свой DNS-сервер, но вам не стоит, судя по вашим вопросам.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала тебе нужно установить статический ip на твоём "сервере", но можешь использовать proxy или иные штуки по типу <<2ip>>
После чего ты должен будешь направить твой домен на установленный, статичный ip. Сам flask запускай с параметрами:

```
server.run(host='0.0.0.0',port='80')
```

Ну и всё, готово.